# Error: Failed to fetch platform android in ionic Framework

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic framework with developing android app.when i add my project "ionic platform add android" getting this problem.

```
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions
Error: Failed to fetch platform android
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: No compatible version found: cordova-android@'>=5.1.1 <5.2.0'
Valid install targets:
["3.5.0","3.5.1","3.6.0","3.6.1","3.6.3","3.6.4","3.7.0","3.7.1","4.0.0","4.0.1","3.7.2","4.0.2","4.1.0","4.1.1","5.0.0"]
```

Comment: check your internet connection

Comment: Just Ty this :-
rm -r ~/.cordova or you can add platform by this way "ionic platform add android@5.0.0".